# Test AWS lambda function via cli

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, lambda, invoke, aws-cli

I want to test a lambda function via CLI instead of the AWS Management console. (Looking to automate function testing by making a bash script)

I've read the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html

I am trying to invoke the lambda function with a json event payload. My bashcode looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

name="arn:aws:lambda:euwest1:100000000000:function:foo"
invoketype="Event"
payload="{'account':'100261334439', 'region':'eu-west-1', 'detail-type':'Scheduled Event', 'source':'aws.events', 'time':'2017-07-16T03:00:00Z', 'id':'178710aa-6871-11e7-b6ef-e9b95183cfc9', 'resources':['arn:aws:events:eu-west-1:100000000000:rule/run_everyday']}"

aws lambda invoke --function-name "$name" --invocation-type "$invoketype" --payload "$payload" testresult.log
```

I am getting the error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequestContentException) when calling the Invoke operation: Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character ('a'
(code 97)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [Source: [B@7ac4c2fa; line: 1, column: 3]
```

I believe I am providing the payload in wrong format, but the documentation has no example, it just says that the datatype is 'blob'. I did some searching but only found info on BLOB (binary large object), but I'm pretty sure this is not what the documentation is referring to.

I have tried without the outer double quotes and replacing all the single quotes with double quotes, but all of these give the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

valid [JSon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) should have key and value between double quotes

so you should have the `payload` attribute written as

```
payload='{"account":"100261334439", "region":"eu-west-1", "detail-type":"Scheduled Event", "source":"aws.events", "time":"2017-07-16T03:00:00Z", "id":"178710aa-6871-11e7-b6ef-e9b95183cfc9", "resources":["arn:aws:events:eu-west-1:100000000000:rule/run_everyday"]}'
```

Answer (score 4):

### tl;dr

Correct (normally): `$ aws lambda invoke --function-name myFunction --payload '{"key1":"value1"}' outputfile.txt`

Correct (Windows): `aws lambda invoke --function-name myFunction --payload "{""key1"": ""value1""}" outputfile.txt`

---

OP's specific question is already answered correctly; this answer is for the benefit of those ending up here with slightly different circumstances from OP. **What OS are you using?** If its Windows, then you are likely pulling your hair out over single and double quote issues.

> Windows command line does not understand single quotes, and double
>   quotes within a quoted string must be escaped as two double quotes
>   ("").

Credit (normal): [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-userapp.html#with-userapp-walkthrough-custom-events-upload)

Credit (Windows): [Hail Reddit!](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/904xw1/aws_lambda_invoke_invalidrequestcontentexception/)

Comment: This is the correct answer for Windows users, i had tried the documentation example but this works!